# Is it advisable to use shared preferences to cache bitmap images? why or why not?

Tags: android, caching, sharedpreferences

I want to cache some of the images in that I am downloading in my android app. The way the caching works is - *The images are mapped to a image name*. So, I can use the cached image until the image name changes.
`SharedPreference` seems to be the best choice at first look, since it provides an in built option to store in the form of key value pairs. The key being the image name and the value being the image in `base64` format. But I read that this is a bad practice. Why? If I store it in an external file I will have to implement the mechanism of key value pairs (which is inbuilt in sharedpreference).
What should be the correct and fast approach and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a horrible idea.  Base 64 is an inefficient way to store binary data.  You have a filesystem-  use it.  Also SharedPreferences are not meant to store that much data, it will cause incredible slowdowns when reading or writing any other data in your preferences.

What is reasonable is to store the bitmap in a file, and the name of the file in a shared preference.  This gives you key value lookup without the bloated size or the parsing inefficiencies of storing it in the shared preferences.

Base64 is really a pretty ugly hack.  It's used when you're putting in ugly hacks and trying to store binary data in a text based interface.  If you ever need to use it, it means you're trying to use a technology for something it was never meant to do and should probably stop.

Comment: This is just the **perfect** answer. Unfortunately, I can't vote more than +1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store the image as bitmap using shared preference. But if there are more images you want to store in sharepreference then dont use it because it will slow down your task.